# ipython doesn't allow creating of classmethods

Tags: python, ipython, python-decorators

I tried using ipython to create a class method with the class method decorator.
When I press enter I get the following error:
[image]

I tried using the same decorator in a normal python script and it worked. Why can't I do the same in Ipython?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem... are you sure you did not press enter twice?

Comment: Yes, I tried it multiple times and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try updating IPython? `pip3 install --upgrade IPython` (the latest version should be 8.15.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your `ipython` package to the latest version, e.g.

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install -U ipython
```

It works fine for `ipython==8.1.0` (released Feb 25, 2022) or later:

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jun 20 2023, 16:52:35) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: class Test:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def test():
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [2]:
```

I could reproduce the issue for the previous version of `ipython`, `8.0.1`:

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.11.4 (main, Jun 20 2023, 16:52:35) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: class Test:
   ...:     @classmethod
  Input In [1]
    @classmethod
                ^
SyntaxError: incomplete input
```